# UNION does not work to combine two results with the same column

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Fwq.png)I am trying to combine these two queries in the same display result but the Mysql system keeps saying that the UNION can not be at this position. If the union does not work, how can I combine these two queries?

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html says:

> To apply an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to an individual SELECT, parenthesize the SELECT and place the clause inside the parentheses:

In your case, it would look like this:

```
(select customer_id, points, state from customers where state = 'CA' order by points desc limit 3)
union
(select customer_id, points, state from customers where state = 'FL' order by points desc limit 3)
```

You may also want to learn about [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html):

```
select customer_id, points, state
from (
  select customer_id, points, state, 
    row_number() over (partition by state order by points desc) as rownum
  from customers where state in ('CA','FL')
) as t
where rownum <= 3
```